# CocoaPods multiple modules in one single Pod, one for static lib, one for swift

Tags: ios, swift, openssl, cocoapods, podspec

I'm creating a Pod for iOS which provides crypto APIs using OpenSSL under the hood.

So far I've managed to call OpenSSL from Swift, but it seems like Swift API and OpenSSL API is mixed up, living in a same `OpenSSL` module.

Is it possible to create `OpenSSL` module for C OpenSSL API, and `OpenSSLTest2` module for Swift API?
Also, I'd like `OpenSSL` module to be private if possible.

Here's my podspec.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'OpenSSLTest2'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'A short description of OpenSSLTest2.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
TODO: Add long description of the pod here.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/yshrsmz/OpenSSLTest2'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'yshrsmz' => 'mymailaddress' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/yshrsmz/OpenSSLTest2.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.swift_version = '4.2'
  s.platform = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

  # if I change here to 'OpenSSLTest' or something, it won't compile 
  s.module_name = 'OpenSSL'
  s.source_files = 'OpenSSLTest2/Classes/**/*.swift', 'OpenSSLTest2/OpenSSL/include/**/*.h'
  s.header_dir = 'openssl'
  s.public_header_files = 'OpenSSLTest2/OpenSSL/include/openssl/*.h'
  s.preserve_paths = 'OpenSSLTest2/Classes/OpenSSL/module.modulemap'
  s.libraries = 'crypto', 'ssl'
  s.vendored_libraries = 'OpenSSLTest2/OpenSSL/lib/libcrypto.a', 'OpenSSLTest2/OpenSSL/lib/libssl.a'

  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
      'SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/OpenSSLTest2/OpenSSL/module $(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/OpenSSL/module',
      'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/OpenSSLTest2/OpenSSL/lib'
  }
end
```

this is the modulemap for OpenSSL.

```
module OpenSSL [system] {
    header "openssl/conf.h"
    header "openssl/evp.h"
    header "openssl/err.h"
    header "openssl/bio.h"
    header "openssl/ssl.h"
    header "openssl/md4.h"
    header "openssl/md5.h"
    header "openssl/sha.h"
    header "openssl/hmac.h"
    header "openssl/rand.h"
    header "openssl/ripemd.h"
    header "openssl/pkcs12.h"
    header "openssl/x509v3.h"

    export *
}
```

also this is the complete repository.

https://github.com/yshrsmz/OpenSSLTest2/tree/0.1.0-pre

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with creating a framework which only contains OpenSSL(with modulemap), and then use that framework as `vendored_frameworks`